# ant classpath cannot find wsdl2java

Tags: ant

i defined an ant task like this:

```
<taskdef name="WSDL2JavaTask" classpath="/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/*.jar" classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.WSDL2Java" />
```

But i am getting:

```
taskdef class com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.WSDL2Java cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/*.jar]
```

i searched online to see which jar file has the wsdl2java class but i am not able to find it. some sources say it is webservices.jar but there is no such jar in the websphere default lib directory.

Comment: I don’t think you can use a file glob like in the `classpath` attribute. You might be able to use a classpath wildcard – does `classpath="/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/*"` (i.e without the `.jar` at the end) work?. Otherwise you may need a nested `<classpath>` with a fileset to include all jar files.